# Filtering django DatetimeField__date not working

Tags: django, django-models

According to this [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#date) that was added on v1.9 we can able to query a `DateTimeField` by date without time.

Examples are:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

But it is not working for me:

```
class MilkStorage(models.Model):
    ....

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
```

**Usage**

```
from datetime import date
MilkStorage.objects.filter(created_at__date=date.today())
```

It returns an empty queryset `<QuerySet []>`.

Does this query only works on `PostgreSQL`? im using `MySQL`.

Comment: You are right, it does not work on my app too, nor the @mohammed-shareef-c suggestion.

Comment: yeah i think i need to raise an issue regarding this on github

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test correctly. It works in my case. Maybe you don't have created any `MilkStorage` today, That is the mistake I did.

Comment: it doest really work for me and i created `MilkStorage` with today's date.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your specific requirements, this may or may not be an ideal solution. I found that __date works if you set USE_TZ = False in settings.py

I had this same problem (I couldn't even filter by __month or __day) until I disabled USE_TZ. Again, may not be ideal for your case, but it should get __date working again.

Comment: confirm this to be the case for me, if you have USE_TZ = true, then __date filter doesn't work.

Comment: I also confirm this, but any other alternative?

Comment: please refer to this documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#date

When USE_TZ is True, fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering. This requires time zone definitions in the database.

Comment: Same here. I guess `__date` is supposed to take the date part after converting the `DateTimeField` value into the specified server timezone when `USE_TZ=True` but it does not work. For now I use a workaround `__contains` and `__startswith` but not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a visitor model. In this model I filtered data through date not time and it's working.

> models.py

```
Visitor(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(_('Login Date Time'), auto_now=True)
    os_info = models.CharField(_('OS Information'), max_length=30, null=True)
```

> views.py

```
import datetime      
visitor = Visitor.objects.filter( timestamp__lte=datetime.datetime.now().date())
print visitor
```

Output:

```
<Visitor: Windows 10>, <Visitor: Windows 10>]
```

Use above way to filter data from date.

Comment: but can you filter it without `__lte`?

Comment: Without `__lte`, you have to append `__date` for an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MYSQL database, you may need to do the following:
Load the time zone tables with mysql_tzinfo_to_sql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

As other people mention, the issue with `__date` occurs when USE_TZ = False in settings.py. Django is really trying to save you from yourself here, but if you know what you're doing, a way you can get the desired behaviour without globally disabling timezones is as so:

```py
from django.db.models import Func
from django.db.models.fields import DateField

class ToDate(Func):
    function = 'DATE'
    output_field = DateField()

qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(my_date_field=ToDate('my_datetime_field'))
# Do whatever you want on `my_date_field` now
```