# check if today is due date django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    due_date_time= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

As due date is a date and time field, how I can check if today is **due date**  of this task , while I am saving time and date both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`__date`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

Tasks.objects.filter(
    due_date_time__date=now().date()
)
```

or if you work with timezones, you can work with a range check:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

today = now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)

Tasks.objects.filter(
    due_date_time__gte=today,
    due_date_time__lt=tomorrow
)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Task` instead of <s>`Tasks`</s>.

Comment: @new1122: did you add the `__date` at the keyword part?

Comment: I did exactly as your solution , seems I am facing this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701151/filtering-django-datetimefield-date-not-working

Comment: @new1122: well that makes sense, since if you use timezones, the definition of "same date", is a bit "fuzzy". After all a timestamp can be in different dates depending on the exact timezone.

Comment: So I have to do  USE_TZ = False   ?

Comment: @new1122: with timezones enabled, you can make a timerange for example for the UTC date.